# NDK does not generate Arm v7 libraries

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm using Android NDK version r8d, I run `ndk-build` but my tool chain does not seem to generate the `armeabi-v7a` directory, it still generates only the `armeabi` directory.

The output says

```
Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.6] libs/armeabi/gdbserver
```

Which indicates that that binaries have been compiled for armeabi only.

Here is my `Android.mk` file.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-9
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_MODULE := test
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    FileOne.cpp \
    FileTwo.cpp \
    FileThree.cpp \

LOCAL_NEON_CFLAGS := -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -march=armv7
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Try `APP_ABI := all`, at least temporarily.

Comment: Hi, I did that already, but didn't work :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`APP_ABI` and `APP_PLATFORM` options should be inside `Application.mk` file, not the `Android.mk` (check the `docs/APPLICATION-MK.html` file in NDK folder).